# Prediction using output of arulessequence R

Tags: r, arules

I am using ArulesSequences package in R to identify meaningful sequences which result in a positive outcome.

```
seq.rules = cspade(test.tran, parameter=list(support=0.01),control = 
list(verbose = TRUE),tmpdir = tempdir())
```

Now I wish to use this list of 'rules' and apply to my test dataset to predict the outcome. I am not able to get material online on how to discover these sequenced rules in a transactional dataset. Any help on this regard would be appreciated. Thanks!